# Insert values from mssql DB and search for value

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I've made a connection with a DB and I want to output a shedule.

```
Date - Room - Event
```

For now I will see every event with the room,

But I want the events to be grouped per room.

so output should be something like

```
Date - Room1 - event 1
               event 2

Date - Room2 - event 3

Date - Room3 - event 4
             - event 5
             - event 6
```

Also, this should be done in the php, not in the sql query.

any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You will need to provide your database schema for the table(s) you need to extract the data from. Surely you need to query the database for the data then output it as you wish with PHP/CSS?

Comment: Could you add the PHP you've written to the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
select date,room,STUFF((select ' '+eventname from yourtable where t.room=t1.room for xml path('')),1,1,'') as events
from yourtable
group by room
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks like something that would work.  but I'm working with kohana framework and it does not take the code like that

What I have atm (just for the rooms)

$zaal = DB::select('Naam')
   ->from('Zalen') 
 
   ->execute()

   ->as_array();

And whenever i put a group_by function in there it gives me an error.

DOException [ HY000 ]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [SELECT Naam FROM Zalen GROUP BY zaal]